# WordPress PHP error after migration - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare previously declared in

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having difficulty working out what's happening here. I've migrated a WordPress install and after some issues with the database, I've encountered this error -

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare theme_register_required_plugins() 

(previously declared in /home/cluster-sites/2/u/union-st.org/public_html/wp-content/themes/zeyn_child_theme/functions.php:26) in /home/cluster-sites/2/u/union-st.org/public_html/wp-content/themes/zeyn/functions.php on line 175
```

I tried wrapping the offending line of code in an If statement, but it seems to have no effect.

Further, the child theme `functions.php` file doesn't even HAVE 26 lines of code in it (and neither does it have another instance of the `theme_register_required_plugins()`.

When I rename BOTH `functions.php` files (effectively stopping them from being read), the error persists...the only way I seem able to affect the error is by renaming the wp-includes folder, which suggests that the problem *might* be there.

I'm a relative newbie to PHP by the way. Thanks for your time :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you get into the admin backend? If so, try and switch to the parent theme, see if that works, and then back to the child. Also check if you have everything up-to-date, or if there are any updates pending.

Comment: No I can't. Even if I rename all of the theme folders, there's no change to the error.

Comment: Then try and change to the parent theme via the database directly, http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/change-theme-in-db

Comment: I didn't even know you could do that - thanks for that.

Comment: That hasn't worked, but interestingly the stylesheet was set to one theme and the theme was set to another. The error is still referring to the Zeyn theme and its child, not Twentytwelve or Twentythirteen, which is what I set it to in the database.

Comment: Can you share the content of child theme functions file

Comment: Sure. <?php 



// Defer jQuery Parsing using the HTML5 defer property
if (!(is_admin() )) {
    function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        // return "$url' defer ";
        return "$url' defer onload='";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}











?>